# How to resolve type not declared errors in V3 Healthcare Finder API Schema?

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

I am a developer, wanted to use the API for one of our website builded in C#.

I tried to convert the schema to C# classes. But it seems that, there are too many "type not declared" error on https://finder.healthcare.gov/api/finder_api_v3.0.xsd

Please suggest.